# Vue js 1.0 call a method within another method throws 'not a function'

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to reuse a method within another of my vue js methods like this :-

```
sendCode: function () {

            this.showSection("SENDING");


            $.ajax({
                url: "someurl" + app.searchResponse.Id,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",

                success: function (result) {

                    if (result.Success) {

                        this.showSection("SMS SENT");
                    }
                    else {
                        this.showSection("SMS FAILED");
                    }

                },
                error: function (error) {

                    console.log(error);
                    this.showSection("SMS FAILED");

                }
            });

        },
        showSection: function (section) {

            return app.ui.currentSection = section;
        }
```

But i get caught Type Error stating this.showSection() is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside ajax callbacks, vue instance `this` is not available because it's a different scope. So declare `$this = this` with a variable before `ajax` and use `$this` inside ajax callbacks.

```
sendCode: function () {

    this.showSection("SENDING");

    var $this = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: "someurl" + app.searchResponse.Id,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",

        success: function (result) {

            if (result.Success) {

                $this.showSection("SMS SENT");
            }
            else {
                $this.showSection("SMS FAILED");
            }

        },
        error: function (error) {

            console.log(error);
            $this.showSection("SMS FAILED");

        }
    });

},
```